# onClick for button not going to JS function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to direct to a JS function using `onClick` but nothing seems to be working, I have tried:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="deleteBtn" onClick="toDelete();">Delete Event</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("deleteBtn").onclick = function() {toDelete()}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("deleteBtn").addEventListener("click", toDelete);
```

This is my function:

```
function toDelete()
    {
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this event?\nPress OK to confirm deletion or CANCEL otherwise");
        if (answer)
        {
            alert("The event has been deleted!");
            <?php
            echo "<form id='deleteForm' name='deleteForm' method='post' action='redirected/deleteRecord.php'>";
                echo    "<input name='EVENT_ID' type='hidden' value='{$EVENT_ID}'>";
                echo    "<input name='eventName' type='hidden' value='{$eventName}'>";
                echo    "<input name='addressLine_1' type='hidden' value='{$addressLine_1}'>";
                echo    "<input name='addressLine_2' type='hidden' value='{$addressLine_2}'>";
                echo    "<input name='townCity' type='hidden' value='{$townCity}'>";
                echo    "<input name='postcode' type='hidden' value='{$postcode}'>";
                echo    "<input name='description' type='hidden' value='{$description}'>";
                echo    "<input name='cost' type='hidden' value='{$cost}'>";
                echo    "<input name='eventDate' type='hidden' value={$eventDate}'>";
            echo "</form>";
            ?>
            document.getElementById('deleteForm').submit();
        }
        else
            location.replace("events.php");
    }
```

Comment: you have invalid js code inside `toDelete`, why you try render html inside js function?

Comment: Why are you echoing HTML in the middle of something that looks like javascript ?

Comment: The HTML is inside the JS because it is a form that is redirected to another. I'm trying to get a confirm and if they want to delete the event, then the form is submitted, else the form is redirected. I tried to do it other ways but because the redirect is determined at the start of the form, it would always do the invalid redirect that I don't want to happen. Regardless of the invalid HTML code, shouldn't the alert still be displayed?

Comment: I have tried to redirect to another JS function using `<button>` and that also doesn't work

Comment: Please show us what your source code looks like _after_ it is output from PHP. Having a look at it may even reveal to you what is wrong with it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This `document.getElementById('deleteForm').submit();
        }
        else
            location.replace("events.php");
    }`

Comment: That is the rest of the function toDelete(); but there is not really any source after that PHP. I have just tried again with an input button that was working to a different function and now it's not

Comment: What I mean is that we don't care what your PHP code looks like. We care about what is sent to your browser. Please do Right Click -> View Source in your browser to see the source, and then paste it here (there should not be any `<?php` or `echo`s in it). However, it seems pretty clear that you have a big chunk of HTML in the middle of your JavaScript and there is no way that is going to work. Please move your HTML _outside_ of your JavaScript and outside of any `<script>` elements.

Comment: write your html code i.e. `<form>..</form>` outside the `<script>` tag.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function toDelete()
 {
  var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this event?\nPress OK to confirm deletion or CANCEL otherwise");
  if (answer)
  {
   alert("The event has been deleted!");
   document.getElementById('deleteForm').submit();
  }
  else
   location.replace("events.php");
 }
  
 
 function updateConfirm()
 {
  alert("Event has been updated!");
 }
 </script>
<button type="button" id="deleteBtn" onclick="toDelete();">Delete Event</button>. That's all the source that's needed, nothing else is sent to the browser

Comment: @WillAshworth Please edit your question to add that.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a sample code snippet with one hidden input field (you can add your php code there).
It works when `<form>` elements are moved outside the `<script>` tag.

```js
function toDelete() {
 var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this event?\nPress OK to confirm deletion or CANCEL otherwise");
  
 if (answer) {
  alert("The event has been deleted!");
  document.getElementById('deleteForm').submit();
 }
 else
  location.replace("events.php");
}

function updateConfirm() {
  alert("Event has been updated!");
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="deleteBtn" onclick="javascript:toDelete();">Delete Event</button>

<form id='deleteForm' name='deleteForm' method='post' action='redirected/deleteRecord.php'>
  <input name='EVENT_ID' type='hidden' value='testid'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with setTimeout

```
document.getElementById("deleteBtn").onclick = function() {setTimeout(function(){toDelete()},500);}
```